# How to pass data privately between React/Preact components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am building a hooks-based responsive table/data-grid component using Preact. Users are expected to use the components as follows:

```
<Table>
  <Column minWidth='150px' key='name' sort={true}>Name</Column>
  <Column minWidth='150px' key='description'>Description</Column>
  <Column minWidth='150px' key='status'>Status</Column>

  <TableData>
    <Row>
      <Cell>Harshal</Cell>
      <Cell>A Great Guy</Cell>
      <Cell>Active</Cell>
    </Row>

    <Row>
      <Cell>Patil</Cell>
      <Cell>Another great Guy</Cell>
      <Cell>Active</Cell>
    </Row>
  </TableData>

</Table>
```

Internally, `Table` and `Column` needs to communicate. Same applies to `Row` and `Cell`. The reason for communication is handling various internal events and managing shared internal state.

As a user, these internal details need not be visible when using them. The question here is how to pass data **privately** between such inter-dependent parent child-components without exposing the details to the calling components!

Comment: I can think of Context API but not sure.

Comment: yes, you could use Context API

Comment: Guess expose would be an option, it's not heavy, you can still keep the code dry since in Table the structure is fixed, and data-flow won't change so much.

Comment: have you got an example of what you mean by shared internal / private state?

Comment: Context is the way to go. Your Table should be a context provider, and the child components should all be context consumers so they can access the context

Comment: @andymccullough There are two examples. `Table` needs to pass grid values to the `Column` component and `Column` needs to tell its new dimensions to the `Table` when it is resized by the user.